# return value by searching for title inside a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

I'd like to be able to search for the array with the title Seattle, which will be set by a variable. Then return the x or y coordinate for that array. I've tried 5 or 6 different ways of trying to locate it without any luck.

This is the query I am using and how I am printing my array:

```
global $wpdb;
$myquery = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_maps WHERE title = 'Test Map'"); 
$mymap =  $mylink->data;

print_r($mymap);
```

This is the actual output.

```
{ "title":"USA", "location":"World", "levels":[ { "id":"states", "title":"States", "locations":[{"id":"bhAAG","title":"Seattle","description":"The City of Goodwill","x":47.6097,"y":122.3331},{"id":"biAAG","title":"Portland","description":"Portland, Maine. Yes. Life’s good here.","x":43.6667,"y":70.2667}] } ] }
```

Same output (formatted for easier viewing).

```
{
    "title":"USA",
    "location":"World",
    "levels":[
        {
            "id":"states",
            "title":"States",
            "locations":[
                {
                    "id":"bhAAG",
                    "title":"Seattle",
                    "description":"The City of Goodwill",
                    "x":47.6097,
                    "y":122.3331
                },
                {
                    "id":"biAAG",
                    "title":"Portland",
                    "description":"Portland, Maine. Yes. Life’s good here.",
                    "x":43.6667,
                    "y":70.2667
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: edit with the really output of print_r($mymap)

Comment: I've added the actual output above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `myMap` data is in JSON format. You can [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it into an array and then search all *locations* for an array with the specified title:

```
$myMap = '{ "title":"USA", "location":"World", "levels":[ { "id":"states", "title":"States", "locations":[{"id":"bhAAG","title":"Seattle","description":"The City of Goodwill","x":47.6097,"y":122.3331},{"id":"biAAG","title":"Portland","description":"Portland, Maine. Yes. Life’s good here.","x":43.6667,"y":70.2667}] } ] }';

// Convert JSON and grab array of locations
$array     = json_decode($myMap, true);
$locations = $array['levels'][0]['locations'];

// What we are looking for
$title = 'Seattle';

// Search locations
foreach ($locations as $location) {
    if ($location['title'] == $title) {
        $x = $location['x'];
        $y = $location['y'];
    }
}

echo "x = $x, y = $y", PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
x = 47.6097, y = 122.3331
```

Comment: That works perfectly, it's exactly what I was asking for. You're the man, thank you for the help. It looks like I didn't get the for each locations as location bit right, but you nailed it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Compact solution *PHP5 >= 5.3*

```
$term = ''; // term being used to search
if(isset($mymap['levels']) && isset($mymap['levels']['locations'])){
    $locations = $mymap['levels']['locations'];

    // filtered will be an array of x, y values
    $filtered = array_map(function($location){
        return [ 'x' => $location['x'], 'y' => $location['y']]; // transform into required format
    }, array_filter($locations, function($location) use ($term){ // filter by title
        return $location['title'] === $term;
    }));
}
```

[`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)
[`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: I've tried it but I receive this error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'. Is there an extra character in there?

Comment: @IYBITWC Oops, sorry. fixed it. Check this back if you really need this.

Comment: Will test and post an update when I get back to this.